# Can I simulate multiple clients this way?

Tags: c, multithreading

I wrote a small server program. I wanted to see how it is handling multiple requests. So I wrote the following program to simulate multiple clients.

Pseudo Code:

```
main()
{

    //set up all necessary data structures to connect to the server

    fork();
    fork();
    fork();

    create_socket();
    connect()

    //more code

}
```

Is there a better way of doing it? What tools I can use to test multi threaded program in C(at least the basic functionality)?

Comment: Well I agree. I just want to send concurrent requests to multi threaded server.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that approach and it arguably the easiest way to deal the problem.  The only caveat is that if the number of clients becomes ridiculously large you might want to move to another design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically created a "process-fan" with this approach, so yes, that can work, although it's not threading ... you're actually creating new processes.  Therefore you will want, in order to prevent zombie child processes, to "wait" for all processes to complete in each process that has spawned a new process.  You could do this with the following line at or near the end of your `main()` for all processes that have called `fork()` (i.e., include the child-processes as well since they are spawning additional processes):

```
while(wait(NULL) != -1 || errno == EINTR);
```

This will wait for all the child-processes the current process has spawned, while preventing any early returns of `wait()` due to your process catching a signal.  When there are no remaining child-processes for the current process, then `wait()` will return `-1` and set `errno` to `ECHILD`, thus exiting the while-loop.